# How to solve error: Cannot Focus element - keyword driven framework in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Keyword driven framework for automate Log in page for one of the site. here I have used Poi for accessing the Excel sheet Data.

Here Below method openBrowser() and openUrl() are working fine. Problem happened for username() method for accessing the username field. I am using Selenium 3.12 and Chrome driver version 2.39 compatible with Chorme

Here is my code :

```
public class ActionKeywords {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void openBrowser(){       
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Pratik_BackUP\\Automation Selenium\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
         System.out.println("open Browser called");

        }

    public static void openUrl(){
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.get("correct url");
          driver.manage().window().maximize();

          System.out.println("open Url called");
        }

    public static void userName(){


        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_login1_pan']/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]")).sendKeys("admin");
        System.out.println("user Name called");
    }

    public static void password(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_login1_pan']/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]")).sendKeys("Camlin@357");
        System.out.println("password called");  
    }

    public static void click_Login(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_login1_LoginButton']")).click();
        System.out.println("LogIn called"); 
    }
    public static void waitFor() throws Exception{
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    public static void closeBrowser(){
            driver.quit();
            System.out.println("close Browser called.");
        }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. You should spend some time reading [ask] and how to provide an [mcve]. You've got a lot of code that has nothing to do with the problem which makes it harder to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks!!

```
public static void userName(){
    WebElement exelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_login1_UserName']"));
    exelement.clear();
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(exelement);
    actions.click();
    actions.sendKeys("admin");
    actions.build().perform();

}
```

Above code works fine. Here have used Actions class for solve [Actions class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)